# Make a method call as soon as back button has been pressed (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, back

In a given activity, an AlertDialog takes the user into WiFI settings. Then, the user presses the back button to return to said activity.

However, as soon as the back button has been pressed I need to make a method call. Please note that I cannot simply add the method after the following code in the activity, as this will impact the time the user has to interact with the AlertDialog instance.

**The method call needs to happen as soon as the back button has been pressed form the WIFI settings menu**. Please inform me of how I can implement this.

Here is the code:

```
alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new dialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
          startActivity(intent);
         }
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `Override` the `onResume()` method of the calling `Activity`. As soon soon as the user presses the "back" `button` the `onResume()` method is sure to get called so you should be able to put your method call here

Comment: The onResume() method is called before the AlertDialog code is executed as this is the normal Android Activity LifeCycle (i.e. Activity starts -> onCreate() -> onStart() -> onResume()). I need the method call to occur after the execution of the AlertDialog code.

Comment: I understand the Android lifecycle but depending on what you need you can set a flag to run certain code depending on when the `onResume()` gets called

Comment: Glad it worked for you. There are other ways but I really think this is the most reliable

Answer (score 1):

class member

```
private static final int WIFI_REQUEST = 1234;
```

Use `startActivityForResult`

```
alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new dialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
      startActivityForResult(intent, WIFI_REQUEST);
     }
 });
```

In the activity class

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    switch (requestCode)
    {
         case WIFI_REQUEST:
              // Call your method here
              break;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that the Wifi Settings dialog will always start in your task, and onActivityResult() is called immediately after startActivity() if the resulting activity starts in its own task.  See the onWindowFocusChanged solution below.

Comment: Yes, if you call startActivityForResult you are guarantee to have the OS called onActivityResult before onResume. I just tested the onWindowFocusChanged is called after onResume.

Comment: You're missing the point though - if in the future the Wifi Settings dialog has a different launchMode (singleInstance, perhaps) then onActivityResult will be called immediately, without waiting for the user to leave the dialog.  Since the Wifi Settings dialog is not documented as returning a result, you should not depend on its launchMode remaining compatible with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean inwifisettings;

public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
    inwifisettings = true;
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
{
    if(inwifisettings & hasFocus)
    {
         doSomething();
         inwifisettings = false;
    }
}
```

You should not use onResume() or startActivityForResult()/onActivityResult() for this purpose.  Quoting the Android documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

> *public void startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode, Bundle options)*
> Note that this method should only be used with Intent protocols that are defined to return a result. In other protocols (such as ACTION_MAIN or ACTION_VIEW), you may not get the result when you expect. For example, if the activity you are launching uses the singleTask launch mode, it will not run in your task and thus you will immediately receive a cancel result.
>
> *public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus)*
> This is the best indicator of whether this activity is visible to the user.
> the system may display system-level windows (such as the status bar notification panel or a system alert) which will temporarily take window input focus without pausing the foreground activity.

Comment: Note that solutions based on onActivityResult() only work so long as the Wifi Settings dialog's launchMode never changes in a future version of Android, and solutions based on onResume() assume that the Wifi Settings dialog will pause your activity.  Neither is guaranteed by the Android platform.  onWindowFocusChanged is the correct way to handle this.

Comment: That will not be changed otherwise startActivityForResult would be good for nothing. The name of the method says it all, one would expect something back.

Comment: ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS is NOT documented as returning a result.  You should not rely on undocumented implementation details, especially things like this that no one on the platform team will expect anyone to be relying on.

Comment: Then the OS will make it so that you cannot called startActivityForResult with ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS. For all the action that go to settings the OS return RESULT_CANCEL. That is why I did not check for the resultCode. I did not expect the OS to change so that it break startActivityForResult. I would be a nightmare.

Comment: Updated with documentation specifically warning you not to use startActivityForResult() for actions that are not documented as returning a result, as well as information warning you not to depend on your activity being paused.

Comment: It is possible but I doubted it will change. Having said that then the solution by codeMagic with a flag is better, because it is called before onWindowFocusChanged. If the OS changed, the onResume may have tons of flags.

Comment: You're still missing the plain words of the documentation.  System dialogs are not guaranteed to pause your activity at all.  It's explicitly stated that this behavior may change and that you should not use onResume() to know when someone's left and come back to your activity.

Comment: onPause is called when another activity comes into the foreground. How can a system dialog is not in the foreground.